# Certificate Moved Permanently

Tags: curl, certificate, ssl-certificate, redhat, ca

I was getting cURL error when accessing HTTPS. I just checked and my ca-bundle.crt contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at curl.haxx.se Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I tried manually updating contents of this file but it keeps reverting. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate was being downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. Had to change http to https.